# Is it safe to call DispatchObject's methods from a background thread?

Tags: ios, swift, thread-safety

Please take a look at the example below.

DispatchQueue's suspend() method is called from the main thread. And the resume() method is called from a background thread. Is this safe?

I've read the documentation for DispatchObject, but it doesn't say whether the suspend/resume methods can be called from a background thread.

Thanks for reading.

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "MyQueue")

queue.suspend()
Task {
    queue.resume() // <-- Is it okay?
}
```

Comment: No don't mix the new Concurrency with the old GCD. They work differently the new Concurrency uses `actor`s not threads. This is built in with the new Concurrency. Watch "Meet async/await". `Task` does not mean "background thread".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally mixing Swift Concurrency and GCD is a bad idea, and @lorem ipsum is correct that `Task` does not mean "background thread." In many cases you should expect it to be on the same thread (since it inherits the current task context as written). That doesn't really impact the question, though, just your example.

The answer is absolutely yes. It would be nice if I could find an explicit statement along the lines of "every Dispatch call is thread-safe unless otherwise indicated" (which is true), but I haven't been able to find anything that broad. The closest is the [statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) that:

> Dispatch queues themselves are thread safe. In other words, you can submit tasks to a dispatch queue from any thread on the system without first taking a lock or synchronizing access to the queue.

Also, GCD would be basically unusable for its purposes if it were not almost entirely thread-safe. In a concurrency library, you should expect the docs to call out when something is **not** thread-safe.

But, while I cannot find a satisfyingly universal statement in the documentation, libdispatch is open source and we can look. The function we want is [`_dispatch_lane_resume`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/main/src/queue.c#L3006), and as expected, it wraps all its work in calls to `os_atomic_rmw_loop2o`, which is a [wrapper around `os_atomic_load` and `os_atomic_cmpxchgvw`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/ee39300b12a77efd3f2f020e009e42d557adbb29/src/shims/atomic.h#L161).

Comment: Thank you for a detailed description. It helped me a lot. happy new year